# ExpressJs: I need an authentication solution to revoke any user access anytime

Tags: node.js, express

Even though there are many solutions for authentications, None of them specifies how can we revoke a user access? I mean maybe as an admin I wanted to ban a user, How can I remove its existing sessions?

Comment: Depends on which auth(/auth) solution you're using, and how the client auth is handled on each request (e.g., if it's a client-side token, you just remove it from the list of auths, if it's on the server side as a session ID then you'd have to figure out how the particular solution handles it).

Comment: If you want to terminate sessions immediatelly, you'd have to track all sessions and check if the session is still valid upon every request. You can store the session id in the auth cookie/token.